# Python: how to click a button in a web page using python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

Below you can see a screen shot of the control group. How can I click this area using python?

[image: image of the script]

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Please provide us with the related code you've tried, along with an explanation of what you were expecting and what went wrong. Add in any relevant error messages you got as well. To get an idea of how to write a good question, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

To click this area using python you need to get work with Python bindings for Selenium. Use next [url to install it](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/installation.html) and [url of how to use it](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html). After getting familiar with content provided by urls above, it shouldn't be a problem to create script which click on button.

After installation of selenium your code to click that button would be quite similar to the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# Go to your page url
driver.get('your page url')
# Get button you are going to click by its id ( also you could us find_element_by_css_selector to get element by css selector)
button_element = driver.find_element_by_id('button id')
button_element.click()
```

Comment: Hi Andriy,
Using your script I'm facing following error. Please suggest.

/c/Python/Python36/Scripts/python.py: line 1: from: command not found
/c/Python/Python36/Scripts/python.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/c/Python/Python36/Scripts/python.py: line 3: `driver = webdriver.Firefox()'

Comment: Pratic, yoou should install gekko driver to use firefox