# How can I call a python program on the event of a button click in my web page?

Tags: python, html

I have planned a simple html page which gets book titles as inputs from the user and on the click of a button returns a review for the book. I am using beautifulsoup from python for extracting review from goodreads api. Below is the code:

```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

   import requests

   bookname = raw_input("Enter the book's name ")

   r  = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/title.xml?&key=lrMttFP2MxZPfHgvb5TiA&title=" +bookname)

   data = r.text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(data ,"html.parser") 
   print(soup.description.get_text())
```

Now I need to get input (bookname) directly from a html page and return the resulting review on the same page.

Comment: Look at this closed question - the answer might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504506/python-how-to-click-a-button-in-a-web-page-using-python?rq=1

Comment: you need to work out how to configure your webserver to call a python script, depending on what you are hosting with will change what is required to get it to work.

Comment: Is there a way to implement the same coding using js? Then I don't have to use python.

Comment: Take a look on web microframeworks like Flask and Bottle

Comment: Update your api key, now the nsa knows it.

Comment: you can do it in JS, but not without leaking your api key. Look at [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [parsexml](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)