# Get Button Click Link

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

Is there a way to get the link of a button click in a website?

This is the Website
https://onlineradiofm.in/stations/mirchi and there is a play button. I want the link to the play button click so that everytime i open the link, the audio starts playing automatically.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click a button element on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418915/click-a-button-element-on-page-load)

Comment: No you cannot get a link from that website. its not a link. its a stream fetching audio bytes periodically from the source.

Answer (score 1):

Add jquery code in the page where you want to click the button on page load.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#button-id").trigger("click");
})

</script>
```

Replace button-id with your button id.

Comment: I dont own the site and Im trying to implement this in android webview. Will it still work?

Comment: No, it will not work. If you don't own the site I guess it's very hard if not impossible to get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no link in the play button, it's a click event. The solution to your problem may differ a lot depending if you own the site you are trying to redirect to the audio or not. In case that the website is owned by you, then you could just create the link you are asking for playing with [query string parameters](https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript) to execute a Js script that clicks the button (like the one proposed by @Pranay kumar 's answer). If you don't own the specified website, then its much harder. In this second case, you could make a python script that clicks the button. An example that may guide you to this solution can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504506/python-how-to-click-a-button-in-a-web-page-using-python/34504610) This should work in your case, but the solution would not be a link, it would be a script.

Comment: Im trying to implement this in android webview. Will it still work?

Comment: Which of the mentioned options? We really need more information to solve your question. Please, provide a detailed explanation of what you are trying to solve and what have you tried.

Comment: Basically im trying to open a website in Android Webview.
Instead of just opening a website, i want to perform button click automatically so that as soon as the user opens the site, the button is clicked and the music will start.

Comment: No, then the python solution will not work. I don't know if you could somehow hack the webview app to inject some js that does the click. It seems possible to me but not easy. Maybe check this link: https://medium.com/@skywall/inject-js-into-androids-webview-8845fb5902b7. If it helps, a vote will be very appreciated :D